# How to mark column with 0 or 1 if data exists in another table in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, data-science, dax

I have 2 tables

1 is a set of employees (Table 1)
1 is a set of terminations (Table 2)

They will both match on an Employee ID column. I want to add a new calculated column to Table 1 that returns 1 if the employee is in Table 2 and returns 0 otherwise. I can't figure out how to write this in DAX. I feel like this should be extremely simple.

I tried

```
 Column = 
    VAR X = RELATED(Table1[Employee ID])
    VAR RES = IF(ISBLANK(X), "no data", X)

    RETURN
        RES
```

This just returns "#ERROR" in all values.

Comment: Can you paste a screenshot of your data model? Are your tables actually related?

Comment: What's the error message DAX is showing?

Comment: I guess table2 is on the many-side of your relation, so you should give Column = IF(COUNTROWS(RELATEDTABLE(table2)) > 0, 1, 0) a try

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your IF statement returns the same data type for both the **true** and the **false** section:

use either

```
VAR RES = IF(ISBLANK(X), "no data", FORMAT(X, "#"))
```

or

```
VAR RES = IF(ISBLANK(X), 0, X)
```

And referring to the title of your question you should actually use

```
VAR RES = IF(ISBLANK(X), 0, 1)
```

Comment: I keep getting the error: "The column 'Table2[Employee ID]' either doesn't exist or doesn't have a relationship to any table available in the current context." The relationships look correct to me. Do you have any insight on this?

Comment: You seem confused. In your question above you were trying to relate to Table1[Employee ID]? Make sure you add the calculated column to the respective other table. Obviously, it is a stupid, simple mistake but you don't even have the skills to describe the problem.

Comment: I'm using different table names in the actual project. The information is confidential. Regardless of that mistake, it doesn't work with either table insertion. I don't understand the error, so obviously I can't describe the problem.